# CasperJS : dropdown list; select an option, code works in browser&slimer but not with phantom

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html-select, casperjs, slimerjs

Here my problem : I'm in a specific case where I try to set the option of a select dropdown list.
I usually use `this.mouse.up() + this.mouse.down()` but I can't in this case because this behavior doesn't work on the website with webkit (you can compare the two with google chrome and Firefox).

Here the url : [I want to set the field 'ANNEE' to a year, 2008 in my example](http://www.linternaute.com/voyage/climat/paris/ville-75056)

My code : (my function changes the HTML and launches the change() event)

```
//custom function
casper.fillSelect = function(selectSelector, optionText){
    this.evaluate(function(sel,setByText) {
        if ("createEvent" in document) {
            var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
                ,x = document.querySelectorAll(sel + ' > option')
                ,l = x.length
                ;
                evt.initEvent("change", false, true);

            for (i=0; i<l; i++){
                if(x[i].textContent.indexOf(setByText) !== -1){
                    console.log(x[i]);
                    console.log(x[i].getAttribute('value'));
                    x[i].setAttribute('selected', true);
                    x[i].parentNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
            }
        }
        else {console.log("error with fillSelect");}
    },selectSelector, optionText);
};

//event
casper.test.on('fail', function(failure) {
    casper.capture('fail.png');
});

/*************************************** Tests *****************************************************/
casper.test.begin('\n********* Compare : ***********', function (test) {
    "use strict";
    casper.start()
    .thenOpen("http://www.linternaute.com/voyage/climat/paris/ville-75056",function(){
        casper.fillSelect('fieldset.fcNeutre > div.odSelect:nth-of-type(2) > select', '2008');
    })
    .waitForUrl(/2008/, function(){
        this.capture('fail2.png');
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h2", "maximales");
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h2", "minimales");
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h2", "Paris");
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h2", "Le soleil");
        this.test.assertSelectorHasText("h2", "La pluie");
        this.test.assertExists("tspan");
        this.test.assertExists("div.marB20");
        this.test.assertNotEquals(this.fetchText("div.marB20 > table > thead > tr > th"), "", "Table first data not empty");
    })
    .run(function() {
            this.test.comment('--- Done ---\n');
            test.done();
    });
});
```

And the equivalent to my casper custom function, you can execute it in the browser :

```
var fillSelect = function(sel,setByText) {
    if ("createEvent" in document) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
            ,x = document.querySelectorAll(sel + ' > option')
            ,l = x.length
            ;
            evt.initEvent("change", false, true);

        for (i=0; i<l; i++){
            if(x[i].textContent.indexOf(setByText) !== -1){
                //console.log(x[i]);
                //console.log(x[i].getAttribute('value'));
                x[i].setAttribute('selected', true);
                x[i].parentNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
            }
        }
    }
    else {console.log("error with fillSelect");}
};

fillSelect('fieldset.fcNeutre > div.odSelect:nth-of-type(2) > select', '2008');
```

So it works in FF, Google Chrome, with slimerJS, but not with PhantomJS ... help please, if you have another idea to just select one option in this 'ANNEE' field, with casper+phantom, I take !

Could it be a problem of browser compatibility?

It's strange because in the same website, sometimes it works with other 'select', identical to this one ...

Comment: Just a note again; please don't edit your answer into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the page already has jQuery in it, I wrote this code and the capture as well as currentUrl shows the change happening. Jquery is able to raise the event correctly. I guess.

I hope you can extract the necessary code from this:

```
casper.on("load.finished", function (status) {
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log('Failed to load page.');
    }
    else {

        var thisurl = casper.getCurrentUrl();
        window.count = (window.count || 0)+1;
        casper.capture('loaded'+window.count+'.png');

        if (window.count ==1) {
            casper.evaluate(function(sel, val){

                jQuery(sel).find("option:contains('"+val+"')").attr('selected', true);  
                jQuery(sel).change();

            }, 'fieldset.fcNeutre > div.odSelect:nth-of-type(2) > select', 2008);
        }

        console.log('Page loaded.' + thisurl);
        //casper.wait(2000, function(){
    }
});
```

Best of luck.

Comment: It works, thank you :) Well I will stop doing that in pure js so.

Answer (score 3):

---

**So my final solution (thanks to sudipto)**

```
casper.fillSelect = function(selectSelector, optionText){
    this.evaluate(function(sel, val) {
        jQuery(sel).find("option:contains('" + val + "')").attr('selected', true).change();  
    }, selectSelector, optionText);
};

casper.fillSelect('fieldset.fcNeutre > div.odSelect:nth-of-type(2) > select', '2008');
```

---

Comment: You can also do `...find('option[value="' + val + '"]')` to search the option value instead of the option text.

Comment: Yep, it depends of your preference !

Comment: I think @kumar303 's comment is not a matter of personal preferences...it is safer than just looking for text "anywhere". Imagine if you have an option that, by coincidence, doesn't have the value you're looking for, but its label matches that value you look for. You option will fail while the suggested one won't. Another comment, I liked your first approach better 'cause this one, even though it works, relies on JQuery, which might not be available everywhere.

Comment: Yes, true. Was the case in **my** case.