# Not possible to trigger GWT listbox ChangeHandler using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, gwt, phantomjs, html-select, casperjs

I'm writing tests using CasperJS for legacy GWT (2.3) code.

I can change the selected value of a ListBox.

```
document.querySelector('#id_of_select').selectedIndex = 1;
```

But this does not trigger the onChange() method of a change handler on the ListBox.

I have tried manually dispatching a change event on the select element (jquery is not available on the page):

```
var evt = document.createEvent("manualchange");
        evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
document.querySelector('#id_of_select').dispatchEvent(evt);
```

I've also tried it this way.

```
document.querySelector('#id_of_select').dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }));
```

Neither approach triggers the onChange method of the change handler. Can anyone suggest a way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery way seems to work in [such cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650944/casperjs-dropdown-list-select-an-option-code-works-in-browserslimer-but-not):

```
casper.fillSelect = function(selectSelector, id){
    this.evaluate(function(sel, id) {
        var select = jQuery(sel);
        select[0].selectedIndex = id;
        select.change();  
    }, selectSelector, id);
};

casper.fillSelect('#id_of_select', 1);
```

To make that work, you can simply load jQuery into the page by either adding a local copy to [`options.clientScripts`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#clientscripts) or a remote copy into [`options.remoteScripts`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#remotescripts):

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    clientScripts: [ "jquery.min.js" ],
    // or
    remoteScripts: [ "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" ]
});
```

There is also [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508688/use-a-select-outside-of-a-form-with-casperjs) of doing this by pressing the mouse button on the select field and releasing it on a specific option:

```
casper.mouse.down("#id_of_select");
casper.mouse.up('#id_of_select > option:nth-child(2)'); // the second option
```